# Leads not 'meeting goal' when converted

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, goals

I have a Journey that sends new Salesforce Leads emails in a sequence every two days, with the 'goal' being that the Leads will convert to Opportunities. I have about 110 Leads that have entered the Journey and I've seen at least three that noticed in Salesforce are converted, but are not showing up as counted toward the Journey goal, despite hitting a Wait or Decision Split activity after converting. I checked the setting of the goal and it is pulling the isConverted field from the Contact -> Salesforce Lead and the criteria is to 'equals TRUE'. Are there some other basic settings that I'm missing that I should check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is that you are dealing with a "complex" scenario. What happens technically, upon conversion is that:

- The lead is soft deleted in marketing cloud by the connector
- A new contact is created in the marketing cloud
- The original lead ID is added as an alternate key in alternate key store

This all assumes you are using SF Record ID's a subscriber keys throughout the system.

The issue, thus, is that the ID of the record that was introduced in the journey, might no longer be available in the contact grid, so we aren't pulling over the updates.

I would engage SF Support to ask how to properly track if a lead was converted in a journey, when Marketing Cloud is not the one who is converting.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, that makes a lot of sense and I figured something like that was happening, and yes I'm using the 18 character Lead/Contact ID as the subscriber key in MC. I'll open a ticket with support.

Comment: Thanks ZackB - did the support solve this for you? :) If you found my answer solved it, please mark it as answered for the question to the benefit of others :) (and help mark the issue as resolved here) :)

Comment: Support said they are working on a feature to fix this, which will be pushed at some date in the future. Marking this solved.