# In Marketing Cloud Journey Builder if a lead is converted to a contact is the contact "created"?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm using the Marketing Cloud Journey Builder. I want to use "is created" an entry source on a Contact object converted from a lead. Will this enter the contact into the journey?

Answer (score 0):

You’ll have to query the `Salesforce_Leads` synchronized data extension to get this converted leads data. Below are a number of related questions on this:

[Check if a Lead is converted after Salesforce Data entry in Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204610/check-if-a-lead-is-converted-after-salesforce-data-entry-in-journey-builder)

[Leads converting to Contacts in Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197522/leads-converting-to-contacts-in-journey-builder)

[Leads not 'meeting goal' when converted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164236/leads-not-meeting-goal-when-converted)